# jquery easyslide help

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, easyslider

Hello I am intergrating the easyslider plugin into my website, I was hoping somebody will have come across my problem, I am using the paginate version of it so I can navigate in the slideshow to any image, however using the paginator then pauses the slideshow, does any one know how I can stop it from pausing and just carry one from the selected images.

The source code is available [here](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)

Comment: @sico87 you really should post your coding attempt to show you've at least given it a whirl.  People are much more apt to help you if you show them code they can debug.  Linking to the plugin page isn't worth anybody's time.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old thread, but this is what I did to fix it...

1. Around line 160 change this:

   ```
   default:
     t = dir;
     break;
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   default:
     t = parseInt(dir);
     break;
   ```
2. Around line 207 insert this:

   ```
   if(options.numeric){;timeout = setTimeout(function(){animate("next",false);},diff*options.speed+options.pause);};
   ```

Worked for me!